# PyMC3 has no attribute hpd

Tags: python, pymc3

I'm trying to use the hpd function but I keep getting an attribute error.

```
import pymc3 as pm
pm.__version__
>>'3.11.4'
pm.stats.hpd()
>>AttributeError: module 'pymc3.stats' has no attribute 'hpd'
```

The complete code (properly passing arguments):

```
def posterior_grid_approx(grid_points=100, success=6, tosses=9):
    """
    """
    # define grid
    p_grid = np.linspace(0, 1, grid_points)

    # define prior
    prior = np.repeat(5, grid_points)  # uniform
    #prior = (p_grid >= 0.5).astype(int)  # truncated
    #prior = np.exp(- 5 * abs(p_grid - 0.5))  # double exp

    # compute likelihood at each point in the grid
    likelihood = stats.binom.pmf(success, tosses, p_grid)

    # compute product of likelihood and prior
    unstd_posterior = likelihood * prior

    # standardize the posterior, so it sums to 1
    posterior = unstd_posterior / unstd_posterior.sum()
    return p_grid, posterior

p_grid, posterior = posterior_grid_approx(grid_points=100, success=6, tosses=9)

samples = np.random.choice(p_grid, p=posterior, size=int(1e4), replace=True)

pm.stats.hpd(samples, alpha=0.5)
>> AttributeError: module 'pymc3.stats' has no attribute 'hpd'
```

I tried pm.hpd and pm.stats.hpd both with no succcess

Comment: What does `hpd` stand for?
From the documentation for [`pymc3.stats`](https://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/api/stats.html#stats-api), there is no `hpd` function present.

Comment: It's Highest Density Probability. I found it on these docs https://pymc3-testing.readthedocs.io/en/rtd-docs/api/stats.html .... Which now I think might be slightly different

Comment: hpd was deprecated a while ago and completely removed recently, you should now use `arviz.hdi` or it's alias `pymc3.hdi`.

Comment: hpd stands for highest posterior density, hdi for highest density interval as intervals can be calculated on any distribution, not only on the posterior

Comment: also @xarles note the documentation you have linked to has `pymc3-testing.readthedocs.io` as domain, I don't know where this comes from nor when it was published, but from the looks of it is is very outdated, you should read the documentation from the official website: https://docs.pymc.io

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was moved to arviz and the code below seems to work

```
import arviz as az

# Calculate HPD credible interval of 95%
ci_95 = az.hdi(posterior_draws, hdi_prob=0.95)
```